# webgpu transferring buffer from js doesnot unpack at right position

Tags: buffer, fragment-shader, webgpu

i am new to webgpu and trying to render some spheres using frgament shader spheres are defined as

```
struct Material {
    category: u32,
    attenuation:  vec3f,
    fuzz: f32,
    refraction_index: f32,
}
    
struct Sphere {
    center: vec3f,
    radius: f32,
    mat: Material
}
```

```
function createSpheresStorageBuffer2(spheres: Sphere[]): GPUBuffer {

    const bufferElements: (Float32Array | Uint32Array)[] = [];
    let size = 0;
    let arrayBuffer;

    for (const sphere of spheres) {
        arrayBuffer = new Float32Array([...sphere.center, sphere.radius]);
        size+=arrayBuffer.byteLength;
        bufferElements.push(arrayBuffer);

        const {type,attenuation,fuzz,refraction_index} = sphere.material;

        arrayBuffer = new Uint32Array([type]);
        size+=arrayBuffer.byteLength;
        bufferElements.push(arrayBuffer);
        
        arrayBuffer = new Float32Array([...attenuation,fuzz,refraction_index]);
        size+=arrayBuffer.byteLength;
        bufferElements.push(arrayBuffer);
    }

    const buffer = device.createBuffer({
        label: "spheres buffer",
        size: size,
        usage: GPUBufferUsage.STORAGE | GPUBufferUsage.COPY_DST,
    });

    let offset = 0;
    for(const buff of bufferElements){
        device.queue.writeBuffer(buffer, offset, buff);
        offset+=buff.byteLength
    }
    return buffer
}

enum MaterialType {
    Labertian = 0,
    Metal = 1,
}

const spheres: Sphere[] = [
    {
        center: [0, -100.5, -1],
        radius: 100,
        material: {
            type: MaterialType.Labertian,
            attenuation: [0.5,0.5,0.5],
            fuzz: 1.0,
            refraction_index: 1.0
        }
    },
    {
        center: [1, 0, -1],
        radius: 0.5,
        material: {
            type: MaterialType.Metal,
            attenuation: [0.5,0.5,0.5],
            fuzz: 0,
            refraction_index: 1.0
        }
    },
]
```

but the value of center of shpere 2 in shader is 0.5,0.5,1 which are the values from attenuation [2,3] + fuzz (which i can to know by trial and error)

the code works fine when the attenuation is f32 instead of vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that the way you are packing your data matches the memory layout from WebGPU

Here's the layout

[image]

The diagram generated from [here](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/resources/wgsl-offset-computer.html#x=5d000001005401000000000000003d888b0237284d3025f2381bcb28899290cefc279bfb15c31b414689329d957887c600e517d3492bd1d01a0f3912d34d95af6ed1540e260e33bd4676019f5a9a76bb3c1f88bebdb2aaf9a2fb084899ca1f2a64c77d04c6f76593cf76f02f0e92fcc1fecfacbd31cea06c73315ff37e897f7bd553b02a285f6dfaca9bd2ae4214c0cc6a452732980185077b11371a308546baf11c450672a495004bd6985760196f791e9f37566aeaf13aa7296e57ce6a660d6811071f9972ad8e6edcac6c713867cc0dc5f3caf9c8eea16788a7e2550ed6f1436015748eca99dbb16cf463455efb26a426)

You might want to consider [using a library to set storage and uniform buffers](https://greggman.github.io/webgpu-utils).

On the other hand, you might also want to consider making one arraybuffer and 2 views. It will be more efficient to upload one buffer than 3 per sphere you're uploading now.

Something along the lines of

```js
const elemsPerSphere = 16;
const f32s = new Float32Array(elemsPerSphere * spheres.length);
// make a u32 view of the same memory
const u32s = new Uint32Array(f32s.buffer);

const kCenterOffset = 0;
const kRadiusOffset = 3;
const kCategoryOffset = 4;
const kAttenuationOffset = 8;
const kFuzzOffset = 11;
const kRefractionIndexOffset = 12;

let offset = 0;
for (const sphere of spheres) {
   f32s.set([...sphere.center, sphere.radius], offset + kCenterOffset);

   const {type,attenuation,fuzz,refraction_index} = sphere.material;
   u32s[offset + kCategoryOffset] = type;

   f32s.set([...attenuation,fuzz,refraction_index], offset + kAttenuationOffset);

   offset += kElemsPerSphere;
}

// Upload all spheres at once
device.queue.writeBuffer(buffer, 0, f32s);
```

See [this article for more info](https://webgpufundamentals.org/webgpu/lessons/webgpu-memory-layout.html)

Note: The method above has performance issues as it's creating temporary arrays for each call to `set`. I don't know if there is an optimal solution. I'd be fine using the solution above until I found it was too slow for my needs. Then I might try something different. One example might be

```js
let offset = 0;
for (const sphere of spheres) {
   f32s.set(sphere.center, offset + kCenterOffset);
   f32s[offset + kRadiusOffset] = sphere.radius

   const {type,attenuation,fuzz,refraction_index} = sphere.material;

   u32s[offset + kCategoryOffset] = type;

   f32s.set(offset + kAttenuationOffset, attenuation);
   f32s[offset + kFuzzOffset] = fuzz;
   f32s[offset + kRefractionIndexOffset] = refaction_index;

   offset += kElemsPerSphere;
}
```

This code at least is not allocating temporary arrays. You'd have to profile if it's faster.

<sup>disclosure: I contribute to the site that generated the diagram and the article and the library linked above and most likely the browser you're using when you asked this question</sup>